# Android - Sequential audio playback?

Tags: android, audio, media-player, sequential, soundpool

Tried both soundpool and mediaplayer but cant quite manage to get sound files to play back correctly in sequence without overlap..  Need to be able to playback three randomly selected audio files in sequence without overlap. Any examples of using soundpool to play back audio sequentially? would be very much appreciated.. seems like such a simple thing is overly complicated..

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest use `MediaPlayer` instead of using `SoundPool`, since purpose of using `SoundPool` is generally to play multiple files concurrently (which causes overlapping.)

Just use a `MediaPlayer` object and apply the [OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) to it.